# Django - Using URL dispatchers in site-level urls.py

Tags: django, url, view, uuid

I want to do something like this where I have a user's uuid in the path of each user-specific app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # URLs for all users
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    ...

    # URLs specific to a particular user
    path('<uuid:user_id>/', UserHomePageView.as_view(), name='user_home'),
    path('<uuid:user_id>/assets/', include('mysite.assets.urls', namespace='user_assets')),
    path('<uuid:user_id>/components/', include('mysite.components.urls', namespace='user_components')),
    path('<uuid:user_id>/service_requests/', include('mysite.service_requests.urls', namespace='user_service_requests')),
    ...
]
```

I'm not sure how this would work. Would the uuid be passed to every view in each of the apps?

I have been searching all over the place, but haven't found any examples of others doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your users have a uuid, assume you over wrote the `User` model with the following:

```
# models.py
import uuid

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    .....
    unique_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```

And from your project root you would have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('some_app/', include('some_app.urls', namespace='some_app')),
    .....
]
```

Then inside each app, every url would have:

```
app_name = 'some_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<uuid:random_uuid>/', views.whatever, name='whatever'),
    .....
]
```

Each view in this app would have:

```
def whatever(request, random_uuid):
    ....
    return render(...)
```

And your templates would pass the `<a href="{% url 'some_app:whatever' user.unique_uuid %}">click here</a>` argument/field to every link that takes it as an argument.

Comment: You're proposing urls like this, which are normally used in django: (mysite.com/assets/d760299d-5da2-46f0-b491-c3c66affc84e/, mysite.com/xyz/d760299d-5da2-46f0-b491-c3c66affc84e/). What I want is urls like this: (mysite.com/d760299d-5da2-46f0-b491-c3c66affc84e/assets/, mysite.com/d760299d-5da2-46f0-b491-c3c66affc84e/xyz/). Basically treating each User like a tenant, except with subfolders instead of subdomains.